# how change top header information in prestashop

Tags: header, prestashop

I want to change the phone number on the header of my website (look the picture: http://www.screencast.com/t/hKIY3ri6u)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have a look: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/191590-solved-how-to-edit-the-topbar-header-menu/

Comment: I just looked but I think it doesn't solve my problem... I want to edit or delete the text (Appelez-nous au : 0123-456-789) on the top of my screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Find your contact block module and change the phone number.

[image]

> This block displays in the header your phone number (‘Call us now’),
>   and a link to the ‘Contact us’ page.
>
> To edit the email addresses for the ‘Contact us’ page: you should go
>   to the ‘Contacts’ page under the ‘Customer’ menu. To edit the contact
>   details in the footer: you should go to the ‘Contact Information
>   Block’ module.

[image]